# PostgreSQL(libpq) version update , PDO, PHP

Tags: php, ubuntu

The Database version I am using 
"***PostgreSQL 9.6.6 (Red Hat 4.8.3-9), 64-bit***"

In my web server I have istalled 'pdo_pgsql'.

**PDO_PGSQL(PostgreSQL(libpq)** version in web server is **9.5**

My PHP version is PHP **7.0**

Note : I have tried to install using the command

```
#apt-get install php7.0-pgsql
```

The version remains same (9.5).

How can upgrade the version of **PDO_PGSQL(PostgreSQL(libpq)** to **9.6**?